# fadein fadeout background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here I am giving you a link [jsfiddle.net/swati712/4Zx5q](http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/4Zx5q) where as you can see by clicking Green Circle `button` on top left hand side, a background image appear as a fadeIn jquery function and once you are out of the image area, that image got fadeOut and grey background reappear. But now I want when someone mouse over any grey area then the image will appear not just click the green button. I know its a very simple task but need help regarding this.

Comment: here is my link: http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/4Zx5q/

Comment: why you don't do the same with selector for you gray div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put the hover handler on the element with the grey background color (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd9e9/1/)):

```
$('#container').hover(function() {
    $(".main1").fadeIn();
    $(".logo").fadeOut();
    $(".logo-left").fadeIn();
}, function(){
});
```

If you're not bothered about restricting the hover functionality to the grey element, and you want to catch the event on the entire page, you could change the jquery selector to target the `document` element:

```
$(document).hover(function() { /* hover code here */});
```

Comment: @net.uk.sweet-I have posted a question just a minute back regarding jQuery. It would be great if you can give some idea on that :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you're saying any part of the grey background fade in the image?  you would do it like this.

```
(function ($) {
    $ (document).ready(function () {
        //TODO: Code here
        $('#left').hover(function() {
            $(".main1").fadeIn();
            $(".logo").fadeOut();
            $(".logo-left").fadeIn();
        }, function () {
        });

        $('.hide').hover(function () {
        }, function () {
            $(this).fadeOut();
            $(".logo").fadeIn();
            $(".logo-left").fadeOut();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with `$(".logo-left")`, that you must change with `$("#left")` and then change `$('.showhide')` with `$(document)` for all page like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('ready', function (){
        //TODO: Code here
        $(document).hover(function () {
            $(".main1").fadeIn();
            $(".logo").fadeOut();
            $("#left").fadeIn(); // here
        }, function () {

        });

        $('.hide').hover(function () {
        }, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
            $(".logo").fadeIn();
            $("#left").fadeOut();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/4Zx5q/8/

Jquery:

```
(function($) {
    $ (document).ready(function(){
        //TODO: Code here
        $('.main').hover(function() {
            $(".main1").fadeIn();
            $(".logo").fadeOut();
            $(".logo-left").fadeIn();
        }, function(){
        });

        $('.hide').hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut();
            $(".logo").fadeIn();
            $(".logo-left").fadeOut();
        });
    });


})(jQuery);
```